# PageViewController bottom dots bug

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller

[what the bug looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aT9F7.jpg)
I'm having this weird action when I use the following code to display those little dots in UIPageViewController. How can I fix it? Is this a swift bug or I'm doing something wrong?

```
func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return numOfImages
}

func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return currentIndex
}
```

Comment: Definitely this is not iOS problem, you are doing something wrong. Be specific about your problem.

Comment: @RajathShettyK just like the image shows, when the user push a button, a page view controller is showed (they are embedded in a navigation view controller if that matters), the bar at the bottom only changed half of its color during the animation. After the animation, the color changed to black like it should be.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get understand bug from picture.for me only weird things is background colours not aligned

Comment: @AlexBains is this screenshot taken, when push is in progress?

Comment: @RajathShettyK yes, it is

Comment: @AlexBains You can try removing navigation view controller. But it is just a guess.

Comment: @RajathShettyK the weird thing is that i have another storyboard in my app, and it is doing exactly the same thing like this one. In that storyboard, all the views are embedded in a navigation controller, and they have the same code like this one. but it works just fine